# How to use C++ modules with a Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make, c++20, c++-modules

I have a Makefile which is minimal, yet complete. It is the following:

```
OUT = example
INSTALL_DIR = /usr/local/bin

OBJECT = ./obj
SOURCE = ./src

SRC := $(shell find $(SOURCE) -name *.cc)
OBJ := $(SRC:%=$(OBJECT)/%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

INC_DIRS := $(shell find $(SOURCE) -type d)
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -pipe -fmodules-ts -std=c++2a
DEBUG_FLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -g -Wall -Wextra
RELEASE_FLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -O3 -flto

debug: $(OBJ)
    @echo "Building the DEBUG binary..."
    @$(CC) $(OBJ) -o $(OUT) $(DEBUG_FLAGS)
    @echo "The binary was built successfully!"

release: $(OBJ)
    @echo "Building the RELEASE binary..."
    @$(CC) $(OBJ) -o $(OUT) $(RELEASE_FLAGS)
    @echo "The binary was built successfully!"

install: $(OUT)
    @cp $(OUT) $(INSTALL_DIR)

uninstall:
    @rm $(INSTALL_DIR)/$(OUT)

$(OBJECT)/%.cc.o: %.cc
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @echo "Building $@..."
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJECT) $(OUT)

-include $(DEPS)
```

There is a directory called "src" which includes the source files. When I'm running make, I will get a compilation error about having to first create modules before using them. If I do create them manually, then I will be able to use "Make" and it will work then it will work. Is there a way to automatically create them?

Comment: Sure.  You write a rule in your makefile to create them, the same way you would any other prerequisite that you need, then list them in as prerequisites in your targets.

Comment: Just to note, your method of building debug vs. release won't work.  The debug and release flags (at least `-g` and `-O`) must be provided to the _compile_ line, not the link line.  They don't have any effect on the link operation.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know a GOOD place I can look up about how to use "prerequisites"?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I should add it to the compile phase and I already noticed that. However, the most important problem for me now is to fix the problem with the modules so I can work and then I will fix the other problem, thanks for noticing and telling me tho!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "use" them.  Prerequisites are the targets listed on the right side of a rule: `<target> : <prerequisites>`.  You can read about rules in the GNU make manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rules.html

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot the word. Ok in this case I suppose that it will work but it will be a pain as I will have to do it manually and I would also have to modify the Makefile every time I add another file. But thanks!

Comment: Well, you haven't really described in any detail at all what you want to do.  But yes, it's possible that when you want to depend on a new module, just like when you want to depend on a new library, you'll have to modify the makefile to add that module as a prerequisite.

Comment: I will just do that! Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Question has changed because I cannot post more questions and I have to imporve the current ones so do not get confused from the existing comments` Och no, this is just horrible, it's a _chameleon question_, please please do not do that.  What is the error message that you get when posting your question? Do you know why you can't post more questions? I'll upvote your question and comments, should give you some karma - can you post another one now? Also, just accept the answer below - for sure you will be able to post a question then.

Comment: @KamilCuk Nah, I still can't. Sorry, I wrote the article and I though this is what I should do. In this case I will just not ask any questions then. Tbh its not life or death questions so I should probably be fine. Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: If you can, try asking at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ that you can't ask another question - I don't know why.

Comment: @KamilCuk Don't worry, there is a link where it explains why this happens. It is here:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `g++-11` instead of just `gcc`, since versions <=10 do not really include module support asides from the deprecated TS. Then also, use flag `-std=c++20`.

Also, I have (painful) experience using dependency files with gcc, since that particular feature is not really fully implemented. Last I checked (beginning of nov '21) the dependency files don't actually do anything as pertains to modules.

That being said, what you write *should* work. And it would, if the compiler-support for modules was finished.

Answer (score 0):

**2023 updated**

## TLDR;

Probably you are not respecting the *order* on compiling the dependencies.

In C++20 modules the order of compilation matters! [This is a characteristic of the technology](https://www.kitware.com/import-cmake-c20-modules/). It also happens in other languages with module system like Fortran, etc.

## `Hello World` Makefile with C++20 Modules

Here is a tested demonstration on how to create a Makefile to work with C++20 modules on GCC 11.2.

If you prefer you can clone the code bellow in [this repository](https://github.com/fvilante/cpp20_modules_with_gcc_demo).

### Project structure

```
Project
|- func.cpp
|- main.cpp
|- Makefile
```

### Makefile

```
.PHONY: all clean run

COMPILER = g++
COMPILER_FLAG = -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts

default: all

run: all
        ./App.exe

all: App.exe

# VERY IMPORTAN! In compilling modules the order of compilation matters. 
# This is a characteristic of the technology. Check for example to swap 
# the two lines bellow:
# App.exe:  main.o func.o
App.exe:  func.o main.o
        ${COMPILER} $^ -o App

%.o: %.cpp
        ${COMPILER} -c  ${COMPILER_FLAG} $<

clean:
        @-rm App
        @-rm func.o
        @-rm main.o
        @-rm -r gcm.cache
```

### func.cpp

```cpp
module;

export module MyModule;

export int func(int a, int b) {  // definition
    return  a + b;
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

import MyModule;

int main() {
    std::cout << "hello world! -----> " << func(1,2);
}
```

### Building and Executing

```
# powershell

> git clone https://github.com/fvilante/cpp20_modules_with_gcc_demo.git
> cd Cpp20_modules_test
❯ make run
./App.exe
hello world! -----> 3
> make clean
```

### Enviroment I tested

- Windows 10
- Powershell 7.2.13
- mingw/gcc 11.2.0 (2021)
- mingw/gnu-make 4.4.1 (2023)

Thank you for reading!